# IE8 Object doesn't support property or method 'on' - object.listenTo - (Backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8

Having some issues with IE8 compatibility with my javascript code that I cannot seem to run down. The code works fine in IE9+, Chrome and FF. I have a backbone.js collection that is listening to a series of other backbone collections for changes in their models. IE 8 is giving an error when applying the event listeners. The code is;

```
for(var k in this.referenceTables){
   this.listenTo(this.referenceTables[k], 'change', this.fetch);
}
```

and IE8 (note: IE10 in IE8 browser mode, document mode IE8 standards) is returning in console the error *Object doesn't support property or method 'on'* at line 2 of the above code.

The above code block is in the initialize function of an a backbone collection.extend.

this.referenceTables is assigned previously in the initialize function with

```
this.referenceTables = options.referenceTables // options.referenceTables is an array of backbone collections
```

I am a bit stumped so any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`for...in` is for iterating over all  enumerable properties of an *object*, if you want to iterate over the values in an array, which `referenceTables` is, you should use a normal `for` loop.

```
for(var k = 0; k < this.referenceTables.length; k++){
```

The problem is that your `for...in` loop is picking up other things from your array object that are not array items, and thus aren't models.

If you were to stick a `console.log(k)` in there, you would see that it isn't just `0...N`.

Comment: Or perform some kind of typecheck `this.referenceTables[k] instanceof Backbone.Collection` but I agree iterating over the array is much nicer.